# React native video not playing when trying to play 3 video at a time in a TV app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, performance

I'm getting this error in the orError callback when I'm trying to render 3 video at a time in using react-native-video in an android tv app. The aim to render 3 or more videos at a time on screen. Some videos load while some don't. I need to understand this error means to optimize my code furthur.

{"extra": -12, "what": 1}}

Tried different ways to optimize but no luck.